# Meta noindex in post and page untranslated (unavailable) with Yoast

Tags: qtranslate, noindex

Is possible enter in the of posts and pages untranslated a meta robots noindex?

Of course, versions already translated, must instead stay indexable ...

I have Yoast SEO plugin compatible but I can not change meta robots per single language.

Comment: which Yoast SEO version are you using? since 3.0 its not usable anymore

Comment: Yoast SEO version  3.0.7

Comment: downgrade to the lastest yoast seo version 2, like 2.3.5. it will play nicely with qtranslate and friends

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in the header of your theme. Language plugin that I use is qtranslate:

```
<!--Begin add noindex and nofolllow when not translated post in current lang-->
<?php if ( have_posts() && is_single() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $lang_current =qtranxf_getLanguage();
    $id = get_the_id();
    $exist_translate = qtranxf_isAvailableIn($id, $lang_current);
    if (! ($exist_translate) ) : ?>
        <meta name=“robots” content=“noindex,nofollow”>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!--End add noindex and nofolllow when not translate post in current language-->
```